# Подключение стадартных библиотек и заголовков в тело функции

Tags: библиотеки, функции

Добрый день! Подскажите могу ли я подключить стандартную библиотеку непосредственно в теле самой функции, и как это можно осуществить?

Comment: Скажите, какой язык программирования вы используете?

Comment: си плюс плюс

Answer (score 1):

Вы о каком языке программирования сейчас говорите?

ОК, мой модуль телепатии подсказывает, что раз в вопросе присутствуют слова "заголовки" и "стандартная библиотека", то речь о C или C++. В таком случае, ответ на ваш вопрос - **нет, так нельзя**. Директива `#include "file.h"` рассматривается препроцессором как указание вставить на её место содержимое файла file.h. Представьте себе:

main.h

```
int main() {
    #include "file.h"
    return 0;
}
```

file.h

```
int somefunc() {
    return 1;
}
```

Препроцессор превратит это в

```
int main() {
    int somefunc() {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

С точки зрения синтаксиса C/C++ это бред.

Итак, ещё раз: **НЕЛЬЗЯ ПОДКЛЮЧАТЬ БИБЛИОТЕКИ В ТЕЛЕ ФУНКЦИЙ**.

Comment: спасибо, это я и имел в виду